# IFrame scrollbar issue in IE7

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, internet-explorer-7

I am working with an IFrame and I can't seem to figure out a way to disable only the horizontal scrollbar in IE7. I need the vertical scrollbar but I want to completely disable the horizonal bar.

Check out the IFrame setup here: [Iframe Example](http://designvillain.com/quittance)

I have disabled horizonal scrolling in the other browsers using:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

But this doesn't seem to work in IE7. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I put the horizonalscrolling line in the Iframe tag thus:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var GB_ANIMATION = true;
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a.greybox").click(function(){
          var t = this.title || $(this).text() || this.href;
          horizontalscrolling = "no";
          GB_show(t,this.href,560,800);
          return false;

        });
      });
    </script>
```

I also disabled scrolling on the body element in the outerpage:

```
html {
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Neither of these solutions have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches:

- The scrollbar isn't a property of the `<iframe>` tag, it is a property of the page that it contains. Try putting `overflow-x: hidden` on the `<html>` element of the inner page which is included in the iframe.
- `horizontalscrolling = "no"` (this is not on documentation though)

It is also interesting to note that you can hide all scrollbars by using `scrolling = "No"` on the `iframe` tag.

Comment: I just updated with your suggestions but I still can't seem to sort out the IE issues. See above -

Comment: @Thomas: Did you try both approaches, also try the overflow on body element.